# How to make directories of iOS projects different from product name

Tags: ios, directory, project

With Xcode 4.5.2, I want to create the project with name 'My App' (using File->New->Project). If you do not add it to an existing project, the following directories are created, assuming you specify the directory 'ios' to xcode:

```
ios/My App/My App/
ios/My App/My App.xcodeproj/
```

When creating the project, you are not allowed to specify the names for the above directories. I want to have this directory structure instead:

```
ios/MyApp/
ios/MyApp.xcodeproj/
```

i.e. without the space in the names and the directories created directly under 'ios'. The product name should still be 'My App', with the space. How would you go about doing this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Product name you can change how:

1) Open XCode project and press cmd + 1

2) Choose your Project at left panel

3) Choose your target at middle panel

4) Tap to 'Build Settings'

5) Find 'Product Name'

Here you can write your product name. Product name is Not depending from your directory names

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. So when creating the project do NOT have the space in the name, which would create the directories without the space. Then change the product name to have a space in it. That takes care of one of the things I need. The second is to get rid of the intermediate 'MyApp' directory and create the 2 directories under 'ios' itself.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting here are the steps for the second part:

```
- Show Navigator pane
- In Project Navigator, select project 'MyApp'
- Show Utilities pane
- Select File Inspector in Utilities pane
- Under Identity, click on the right arrow next to the Full Path of the project directory
- In the Finder that pops up, rename the parent MyApp to xyz. You'll see a popup that promts to either 'Close' or 'Re-save'. Select Close.
- The xcode window disappears.
- In the Finder, move MyApp and MyApp.xcodeproj one level above from where they are - i.e. to be at the same level as xyz.
- Delete xyz
- Double-click on MyApp.xcodeproj to open it in xcode.
- It should now work
```